Can a bottom drawer common in mobile apps be used on mobile webpages?
I was trying out the GenAI features in Instagram, and loved how they used a drawer for hiding information a user doesn't need all the time. Can this pattern be implemented on web through either native OS functionalities or custom builds? Is this a good pattern to build for mobile web?
  


Mobile web patterns should always take responsive behaviours and environments into consideration. How do you see the bottom draw scaling up to a user with a mouse on desktop? Essentially the bottom drawer is just a unique mobile-based display of a modal+light-box.

all mobile patterns aren't intended to scale to web, and vice versa. For e.g. mobile cannot handle hover. I am looking for a response on if a 'drawer' on mobile web makes sense

Without knowing the use case and information displayed, I can't actually speak to whether a drawer is a "good" pattern to use. But to any mobile web users the behaviour difference between a drawer and modal would be mostly arbitrary. A modal could possibly be the more recognizable feature but if you're not bringing design options to a competitive usability test, picking either pattern is perfectly cromulent.
